# Android resource linking failed after Android Update 3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After the Android SDK 28+ update, I updated my gradle to version 5.5.1 and gradle plugins to 3.4.2
I am getting the following error and this is very irritating because i dont think my code is wrong!

***"Android resource linking failed
warn: removing resource com.anirudh.gighub:string/com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_f1gender without required default value.***

***F:\gigHub\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1437: error: resource dimen/smallTxtSize (aka com.anirudh.gighub:dimen/smallTxtSize) not found.***

***F:\gigHub\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1438: error: resource drawable/facebook_signin_btn (aka com.anirudh.gighub:drawable/facebook_signin_btn) not found.
error: failed linking references."***

```
Here is the build.gradle

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.anirudh.gighub"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}


Here is the App Manifest file:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.anirudh.gighub">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:appComponentFactory="whateverString">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Register" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart**

Comment: Tried both Rebuild and Invalidate Caches! Same problem!

Comment: I have added build.gradle and manifest files.Please check through that and see if there is any mistake there.

Comment: I have searched it everywhere cannot find any solution to this!

Comment: @AnirudhVashisht most probably, you added your dimens and drawables in wrong folder. Like, instead of putting drawable in drawable folder, you have put it in drawable-xxhdpi folder or something similar